# How I can Schedule Job in Quartz using Task<IScheduler> scheduler

Tags: c#, quartz.net, quartz

While doing

- scheduler.Shutdown(); ,
- scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
- scheduler.DeleteJob(new JobKey(job, group));

It gives an error.

[image: Error image]

```
private static RikyasScheduler instance = new RikyasScheduler();

    private Task<IScheduler> scheduler = null;
    public RikyasScheduler()
    {
        scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Methods
    public void StartScheduler()
    {
        try
        {
            scheduler.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }
    }

    public void StopScheduler()
    {
        try
        {
            scheduler.Shutdown();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }
    }


    public void AddJob(IJobDetail job, ITrigger trigger)
    {
        try
        {
            scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }
    }

    public void RemoveJob(string job, string group)
    {
        try
        {
            scheduler.DeleteJob(new JobKey(job, group));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }
    }
```

Comment: Shutdown, ScheduleJob, DeleteJob, are these methods defined in your IScheduler interface? Task<T> doesn't have these methods.

Comment: scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler(); this line will acutally call GetDefaultScheduler() method asynchronously.  You should then use scheduler.Result to get the actual schedule instance.

Comment: @ojlovecd no it does not define.

Comment: @NileshShinde can you figure out this ?

Comment: @NileshShinde done it.  scheduler.Result.ScheduleJob(job, trigger); thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Answer By : You should then use scheduler.Result to get the actual schedule instance. – Nilesh Shinde
scheduler.Result.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);